# Can't display my query object in angularjs using ng-repeat querying with odata

Tags: angularjs, api, odata

I'm trying to figure out how to display a list of companies from an Entity Framework table. I'm using odata, and it currently works to getById and pass it an id manually. However, when I use my `getAll()` method to to grab all of the companies I can't get it to work. In my html I use something like this in a select dropdown menu: ng-repeat="company in companies"{{company.CompanyName}}. When I do this all I get are like two blank selections with no names no nothing. Can someone give me some advice?

This is my controller:

```
'use strict';

define(['app', 'js/services/companies'], function (app) {

    var register = app.register || app;

    register.controller('companyUpdateIndexCtrl', ['$scope', 'companies', function ($scope, companies ) {

            companies.getById(2932).success(function (data) {
            $scope.company = data;
        }).error(function (data) {
            //handle error
        });
            $scope.companies = companies;
            companies.getAll().success(function (data) {
                $scope.all = data;
            }).error(function (data) {

            });
    }]);

});
```

This is my html:

```
<div data-ng-controller="companiesIndexCtrl">
<div><label style="padding-right:25px">Select a Company</label>
    <select ng-model="companies.CompanyName">
        <option ng-repeat="x in companies">{{x.CompanyName}}</option>
    </select>
```

My api function:

```
    api.prototype.getAll = function (data) {
        return dataService.get(this.baseUrl + odata.queryString(data));
    };
```

Using api function:

```
'use strict';

define(['app', 'js/services/api'], function (app) {

    var register = app.register || app;

    register.factory('companies',  ['api', function (api) {

        var Companies = new api('Companies');
        return Companies;
    }])

});
```